# Data is missing after restore in interbase XE7

Tags: interbase

I have migrate Borland interbase 7 to embarcadero interbase XE7 database. I have taken backup file *.ibk using IBConsole and restored into interbase XE7 and successfully restored the database on interbase XE7 database but when i randomly verify data on a tables named "INVENTOR","KITS_BLT","COMMODITY" etc. ,no data found on that tables ,but some tables are having data.

I have included backup log file(https://www.dropbox.com/s/s6723hmo7rxa6n2/backup.txt?dl=0) and restore log files(https://www.dropbox.com/s/pmgvqslr3bj7j0w/restore.txt?dl=0) both are showing INVENTOR having 176206 ,KITS_BLT having 3010579 records,COMMODITY having 15 records.

I could not understand, why the some tables having data and some have not ?
please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: How do you verify that you have no records in these tables? Did you run select Count(*) from table or you enter to it by ibConsole? I suppose that you not move your **udf dll's** from old interbase to the new. And when you go to table which have computed by column then ibConsole(or your other tool) silently ignore this error.